# How do I add indent-based folds to new lines?

Tags: folding

I have my `.vimrc` set up with indent-based folding.

But when I make additions to a file, the new text is not foldable.  I can manually add folds, but I'd rather not.

Is there a way to make vim look over the file and create indent folds for all the current contents?

```
set foldmethod=indent
set foldenable
set foldlevel=0
augroup vimrc
  au BufReadPre * setlocal foldmethod=indent
  au BufWinEnter * if &fdm == 'indent' | setlocal foldmethod=manual | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: Are you talking about `foldmethod=indent`? It's not really clear what you mean. At any rate, note that `foldmethod` is a local option, so you probably want to set it via an ftplugin or an autocommand for the buffers that you care about (rather than setting it once in a vimrc).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I do have foldmethod set to indent.  But this does not apply to indented text that was added since the file opened.  Sounds like I can configure vim to set the foldmethod on write?

Comment: I think setting foldmethod on write is probably unrelated/not what you want to do in the long run. Open a buffer with the "wrong" behavior and try `:setlocal foldmethod=indent foldenable`. The folds should _definitely_ be updated as you edit text if the `foldmethod` is indeed `indent`. Also see [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604). How do you know it does apply to text you add? You can check folds with, for example, the foldcolumn

Comment: @D.BenKnoble if I create a new js file, for example, and write some nested stuff in it, then save, then execute `:setlocal foldmethod=indent foldenable`, the nested stuff folds as expected.  Editing answer to include `foldmethod`-related stuff from my .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had some commands running on `BufWinEnter` that set the fold method to manual.  Probably going to just manually switch modes if I actually need manual folding.

Thanks to [D.BenKnoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) for the breadcrumbs.